# Is a bounded sequence times a unbounded sequence bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

And similarly is a unbounded sequence times a convergent sequence bounded?  I'm still getting familiar with the properties of sequences.

Comment: What if you multiply a sequence by the sequence $1,1,1,\ldots$?

Comment: What simple examples of sequences do you know? Try them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unbounded sequence times a sequence that has at least one nonzero convergence point is actually always **un**bounded.

That should answer both your questions. For a concrete counterexample, take any unbounded sequence and the bounded sequence $1,1,1,\dots$

Comment: What about the sequences $a_n = \frac{1}{2}(-1)^n+\frac{1}{2}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{2}(-1)^{n+1}n+\frac{1}{2}n$?

Comment: Apologies for digging up a fossil of a post, but the sequence $b_n$ is clearly unbounded and the sequence $a_n$ has a non-zero subsequential limit, namely $1$. However, $a_n b_n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A counter example shows both:
$a_n = 2$ is bounded, and  $b_n = n$ is unbounded.But $a_nb_n = 2n$ which is unbounded, so we don't have the first. Also $a_n = 2$ converges to $2$, so it covers your second part as well.